# How do I use multidimensional arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

How would I use multidimensional arrays to store an x and y coordinate and the value that should be displayed at that coordinate. The swing tutorial really confused me and im not sure if you can read them the same way as a normal array. Here are my previous attempts:

```
private int[][][] idXY = new int[1000][1000][2];
int id;

public int[][] idPos(int x, int y){
    return idXY[x][y][id];
}

public void setID(int x, int y, int ID){
    idXY[x][y][ID] = {x}, {y}, {ID};
}
```

Im very sure that code doesn't make sence XD.

Thanks for your help,

AidoP

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @Doorknob Does this mean that non-experts are unwelcome on Stack Overflow, and questions by inexperienced programmers are not tolerated?

Comment: @AndersonGreen No, it means that you have to show what you have tried, what you want, etc.

Comment: @AndersonGreen It also means I need to know the language, enough to ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax to store a value to a multidimensional array:

```
array[x][y] = value;
```

To access it:

```
array[x][y];
System.out.println(array[x][y]); // as an example
```

Comment: This worked, but how would I read it to get the value?

Comment: Ok, the Oracale tutorials really confused me when reading the value, Thanks.